# intro.js dontShowAgain

Tags: javascript, json, intro.js

How do I use [dontShowAgain](https://introjs.com/docs/examples/basic/dont-show-again) in combination with setting steps as a [JSON configuration](https://introjs.com/docs/examples/basic/json-config)? They are both invoked using .setOptions(), but have different syntax?

I tried to call both, but naturally the last call of .setOptions() overrides the prior.

Comment: one is `.setOption("dontShowAgain", true)` it sets a single option, would use that if you have conditions on the options, if not use setOptions with an object, add `dontShowAgain: true,` in the object you pass

Comment: Here is what I am using, and the little "don't show again [x]" box isn't appearing as demonstrated.

`introJs().setOptions({dontShowAgain: true, showBullets: false, steps: [{title: 'Farewell!', element: document.querySelector('.actor'), intro: 'This is an actor!'}]}).start();`

Answer (score 0):

Just add option prop:

```
      <Steps
        steps={steps}
        onExit={onStepsExit}
        enabled={stepsEnabled}
        initialStep={initialStep}
        onBeforeChange={onBeforeChange}
        options={{
          showBullets: false,
          dontShowAgain: true,
          disableInteraction: false,
        }}
      />
```